# Collinearity in polynomial regression

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity

I executed some experiments to find the influence of x on z. It shows that z is also correlated to y. To find the influence of x without ignoring y's influence, I tried to find a model z(x,y) with polynomial terms (max. 3rd power):

I compared some fits and chose 
`fit1: z = B0 + B1*x + B2*x² + B3*y + B4*y²`

This fit seems good (adj. R² = 84%, all p's << 0,05). 
But looking at my standardized regression coefficients (betas), to estimate the influence of x and y on x, I get betas > |1|.

So my questions are:

1. **This is due to the collinearity, right?**
2. **Is collinearity a problem in this case?** (Do I have to get orthogonal polynoms?)
3. **Are betas above |1| valid to estimate the "size" of influences?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Introduction of higher powered terms will invariably result in issues of multicollinearity.  This is essentially unavoidable.  Thus, it is best to only include the terms if theoretically justifiable.  (That's the standard caveat spiel...now that that’s out of the way...)

Though you cannot have a standardized coefficient greater than one in a bivariate regression, it is possible in multiple regressions.  If you do observe them, then you would justifiably be weary of the results.  One possible strategy is to run the regression with mean centered values.  Instead of using $x$ and $y$, replace them with $x_c = x - \bar{x}$ and $y_c = y - \bar{y}$.  Then you can use the higher powers of these “smaller” variables:  $x_c^2$ or $y_c^3$.  This may address the problem here, as the issue of collinearity may decrease (depending on the distribution of $x$ and $y$) if you are using just the quadratic terms.

Hope this helps...and always happy to elaborate further if need be.

Comment: "Invariably" may be too strong and certainly needs some nuanced qualifications.  When the values of $x$ and $y$ have approximately symmetric distributions around zero, including their squares may create little collinearity.  Regardless, the question concerns how the standardized coefficients might be related to collinearity: do you have an answer to that?

Comment: `@Gregg H`: Thanx for this Answer. By using xc and yc I can indeed get smaller betas. I just don't know how to interpret them. I need these betas to estimate the "size" of an influence. With xc and yc I get completely different sizes than with x and y (example: y² now seems to have more influence than y, opposite as before). Not including higher powers would be good. I only allowed them because they seem to really optimize the fit (AIC and R²). But maybe this is only because there are more terms. Can this be checked some way?

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a model with just the linear terms (centered or not), and then plot the residuals (observed y - predicted y) against each of the independent variables. If you observe any suggestion of a nonlinear trend (e.g., a U-shaped pattern), this would suggest including the quadratic terms is warranted. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it is kind of U-Shaped

Comment: Then I'd include the quadratic term